# How do I get my div to be a minium height of browser window but able to grow aswell

Tags: jquery

Im using this slip of jQuery that detects the height of the browser window and sets the height of a div the same height but I'm having a problem. My problem is that the div ONLY goes as far as the height of the browsers window but no longer. I need the div to be a minimum height of the browser window but be able to contiue longer if it needs to

FYI I am a jQuery noob  :P

Currently this is what the problem looks like:
http://d.pr/i/OQyp

This is the code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.projects-about') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.projects-about') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `min-height`?

```
$(function(){
    $('.projects-about') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.projects-about') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: You might want to use the throttle plugin to not have a callback after each pixel. But only after 250 MS like the plugin @DanFarrell posted. Found here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: @Niels Nice comment, I have a project that could use something like that!

Comment: I use it if performance is important. If you develop for mobile you don't want too many resize events.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `min-height`

```
$('.projects-about').css({'min-height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
```